# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file raised on capturing raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple method that takes a string passed to it and determines if the user was confirming their selection or not. The idea is that a user can type 0 to exit from the program all together. Whenever a user selects 0 though I receive `ValueError`. Is it something I implemented in my while loop?

## Notes

`self.YellowBold` will simply color text with ANSII escape characters.

`self.CleanUp` does open and close a log file before exiting. This method however has never caused a problem in my program and is called often and will exit the program.

```
def AskConfirm(self, answer):
    # Used throughout the script for all confirmations.
    # Try to force the answer to a lower case string. Bring up the prompt again if it fails.

        yes = ['yes','y']
        no = ['no','n']
        codes = ['0'] # Can be expanded later for other options

        while True:
            try:
                answer = str(answer).lower()

                if answer in yes: return True
                if answer in no: return False
                if answer in codes: self.CleanUp()

                raise Exception

            except:
                answer = raw_input (self.YellowBold("Please respond with 'y' or 'n' or '0' to exit: "))
                continue
```

### Error

```
answer = raw_input (self.YellowBold("Please respond with 'y' or 'n' or '0' to exit:"))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

### CleanUp

```
def CleanUp(self): # Exit and add a breakpoint to the log file.
    open_log = self.OpenLog()
    open_log.write("-"*50 + "\n")
    exit(1)
```

### Solution

My exception was too broad and using exception as flow control in this case did not work because of the interaction with CleanUp(). I reworked my flow control.

```
def AskConfirm(self, answer):
        yes = ['yes','y']
        no = ['no','n']
        codes = ['0'] 
        prompt = self.YellowBold("Please respond with 'y' or 'n' or '0' to exit: ")

        while True:
            answer = str(answer).lower()
            if answer in yes: return True
            if answer in no: return False
            if answer in codes: self.CleanUp()

            answer = raw_input(prompt)
```

Comment: So your `stdin` is closed. What context is this in? Is this running in a terminal, a console, an IDE, or as a GUI? We need more context to help more.

Comment: No problem, this is part of a script that I wrote for our help desk guys. It is meant to be run from the terminal and all prompts/actions take place at the CLI. 

This method gets called if one of our help desk guys makes a selection, say a directory to perform an action on. The user would then be prompted with raw_input asking if that is the choice he wanted. Whatever string he types would then be passed to this method.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any context here for us to reproduce your issue. Normally your `stdin` remains open when run in a terminal.

Comment: Is it possible the error is caused by the interpreter returning to this method after calling  self.CleanUp() even though it should exit entirely? I imagine then the interpreter would hit my raise exception and try to print something to stdout and error out.

Comment: I added my CleanUp method into my question for clarity.

Comment: Absolutely; you are catching **all** exceptions, including [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a blanket `except` and catching the `SystemExit` exception raised by `exit(1)`. It looks like `stdin` is already closed by that time.

You need to be more selective in what exceptions you catch. You could limit to `Exception`:

```
except Exception:
```

but that's still to wide a net, even though `SystemExit` is then no longer caught (it inherits from `BaseException`).

There shouldn't really be *any* exceptions to catch here anyway, `str()` is very flexible as all objects should have a working `__repr__` implementation to fall back to.

This is sufficient for your specific prompt:

```
    while True:
        answer = str(answer).lower()

        if answer in yes: return True
        if answer in no: return False
        if answer in codes: self.CleanUp()

        # if we haven't returned, ask again
        answer = raw_input (self.YellowBold("Please respond with 'y' or 'n' or '0' to exit: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simplified version of this code and it works without any errors. Here is the code:

```
yes = ['yes','y']
no = ['no','n']
answer = 'c'
def magic(answer):
    try:
        answer = str(answer).lower()
        print answer
        if answer in yes: return True
        if answer in no: return False
        raise Exception
    except Exception:
        print answer
        answer = raw_input ("Please respond with 'y' or 'n' or '0' to exit: ")
        print answer
        pass

magic(answer)
```

I am suspecting that the problem is somewhere else. Perhaps You have opened a file but not closed it in `except` block. Need more code to reach conclusion.